# angular.js http.get() service not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not exactly sure where I'm going wrong but when I put my data into a separate .json file and used $http.get() to retrieve that data my scatter chart isn't visualizing anymore. Here's my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bJE8qTG8CEI957xKMh6q?p=preview

Specifically these lines I feel I might be making a mistake:

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
    $scope.exampleData = response.data;
```

Comment: do you have a property `data` in your response object? if not it is just `$scope.exampleData = response`

Answer (score 0):

the `$http.get()` works fine.

There is an error below:

`app.controller('ExampleCtrl', [$scope, $http, function ($scope, $http){`

should be

`app.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http){`

and your json doesn't contain a `data` prop so change `$scope.exampleData = response.data;` to this `$scope.exampleData = response;`

also

```
var colorArray = ['#000000', '#660000', '#CC0000', '#FF6666', '#FF3333', '#FF6666', '#FFE6E6'];
$scope.colorFunction = function(){ 
  return function(d, i){
    return colorArray[i]; 
  };
}
```

needs to be in a controller; you get $scope is undefined if it isn't

**edit**

PSL is right, there is no `data` prop in the object, but still the original plnkr had errors in it. The `get()` worked just fine which was answering OPs question.

Comment: if you're going to downvote my answer, please leave a reason as to why. Please explain why this isn't working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ACS7S7JXx2P18M4Ce53C?p=preview  screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/4MZyKna.jpg

Comment: I edited the file for the few errors...but again the scatter chart is still not visualizing. My real question is..what is preventing the app from working? Of course I wouldn't down vote, you're trying to help. It is, however, discouraging when I come to a reputable tech help forum and get 3 down votes for something I consider pertinent.

Comment: yeah I dont understand the downvotes. Anyway, to get the scatter plot to show, change this `$scope.exampleData = response.data;` to this `$scope.exampleData = response;`

Comment: Awesome thank you. If I were to separate this into a service and controller I am under the impression this would essentially be it...but again now it's not visualizing for some reason. http://i.imgur.com/1vvNlsA.png